# background image in html page in iphone

Tags: iphone

I m the beginner in iphone development.

How i call the background image from my project directory in Xcode in html page. I have taken previously UISegment control and after that i calling two html page on webview in uisegmentcontroller.
Now i want to set background images on those html pages.
It is possible?
if it is yes then how?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a base URL when loading HTML in a UIWebView. If you set the base URL to your bundle path, you can simply reference the background image as if it was in the current directory.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlPage baseURL:baseURL];
```

in your HTML:

```
body { 
  background: url(bg.jpg); // "bg.jpg" is in your bundle
}
```